# Java implementation-How to improve the speed of hash table

Tags: java, performance, key, hashtable

I am implementing a hash table (as per requirements). It works ok with a small input but unfortunately it's way too slow when dealing with a large number of input. I tried `BufferedInputStream` but it doesn't make any differences. Basically I implemented it following the logic below. Any ideas how I can improve the speed? Is there a specific function that causes the bad performance? Or we might need to close the Scanner?

```
 int [] table = new int [30000];// creat an array as the table
 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); //use scanner to read the input file. 
 while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
       //read one line at a time, and a sequence of int into an array list called keys  
       // functions used here is string.split(" ");
 }
 hashFuction{
       //use middle-squaring on each elements to the array list keys. 
       // Math.pow() and % 30000, which is the table size, to generate the hash value
       // assign table [hashvalue]= value
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to at least figure out if it's I/O that's the bottleneck or if it's your hash table. How does your program perform if you use `HashMap` instead of your class? If it's your hash table, we'll need to see the code for it.

Comment: Thanks. can you recommend a way of check which part of a program is the bottleneck?

Comment: Rewrite your code to use `HashMap` and see how fast it runs then. If it's fast, then the problem must be in your hash table class. If it's still slow, then the problem is outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

So first, you should now what part of the program is slow. Optimizing everything is a stupid idea, optimizing the fast part is even worse.

> Math.pow() and % 30000, which is the table size

This is pretty wrong.

- Never use floating point operations for things like hashing. It's slow and badly distributed.
- Never use a table size which is neither a power of two nor prime.

You failed to tell us anything about what you're hashing and why... so let's assume you need to map  a pair of two ints into the table.

```
class IntPair {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int hashCode() {
        // the multiplier must be odd for good results
        // its exact value doesn't matter much, but it mustn't equal to your table size; ideally, it should be co-prime
        return 54321 * x + y;
    }

    public boolean equals() {
        do yourself
    }
}

//// Prime table size. The division is slow, but it works slightly better than power of two.

int[] table = new int[30011]; // this is a prime

int hashCodeToIndex(int hashCode) {
    int nonNegative = hashCode & Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return nonNegative % table.length;
}

//// Power of two table size. No division, faster.

int[] table2 = new int[1<<15]; // this is 2**15, i.e., 32768

int smear(int hashCode) {
    // doing nothing may be good enough, if the hashCode is well distributed
    // otherwise, see e.g., https://github.com/google/guava/blob/c234ed7f015dc90d0380558e663f57c5c445a288/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Hashing.java#L46
    return hashCode;
}

int hashCodeToIndex(int hashCode) {
    // the "&" cleans all unwanted bits
    return smear(hashCode) & (table2.length - 1);
}

// an alternative, explanation upon request
int hashCodeToIndex2(int hashCode) {
    return smear(hashCode) >>> 17;
}
```

Comment: +1 Using floating point does have to be bad, but it is unnecessarily complicated and Math.pow is slow. Using & is fastest but doesn't have a great distribution if hashCode is not perfect. It works better for low load factors.